# sudo apt-get install tomcat7 returns a 404 for Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) but package should be available

Tags: 14.04, apt, tomcat7

I'm trying to install tomcat7 on ubuntu 14.04 64bit using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

the required libs can't be downloaded with the following error

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main icedtea-7-jre-jamvm amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/icedtea-7-jre-jamvm_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried the sugggested `--fix-missing` but still getting the same error, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: for me it works, I have the same setup. 14.04 (64bit)

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/   says it should be there, please try to install for example tomcat7-admin  , just for a try, does he find the package?

Comment: @Private it didn't find the package, I think it has some thing to do with me being in Syria as the addresses in error messages are all Syria-specific

Comment: yep, maybe this helps : http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: did you try with `sudo apt-get update` or try with `sudo apt-get --fix-missing`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt tries to download an outdated version, currently this is the most recent version found there:

```
openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04_amd64.deb
```

You need to run `apt-get update`.